# generating Hidden from list properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry folks it may be a basic thing but I m newbie.

My model is a list which has two properties, and I need to generate HiddenFor for 1 or both of properties. Inside loop I m trying to generate HiddenFor using below code:

```
@foreach (StoredDocument doc in @Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(@doc.Document);
    <img src="@doc.Document" />
}
```

But not sure where I am wrong, I m getting message:

*The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
@foreach (StoredDocument doc in Model) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => doc.Document);
    <img src="@doc.Document" />
}
```

Keep in mind that this may not post back to the server the way you want it to. You should set it up so your model is an array of StoredDocument, and not just an `IEnumerable<StoredDocument>`

```
@model StoredDocument[]

@foreach (int i = 0; i < Model.length; i++) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].Document);
    <img src="@Model[i].Document" />
}
```

Comment: Really thanks DigitalID, much appriciated. Just to clarify do you mean using a List I will not able to get values of List back on server and to get values of list back on server I should use array ?

Comment: I mean using an array, not a List<T>. It really depends on why you want to have hidden fields in the first place.

Comment: DigitalID it is really a uncommon scenario to me, from previous page I m adding some images to page by drag and drop. I cant save images in first page because save button is in page 2, I m passing images as hidden to server then I need to show sames images on page two, from where clicking save will save data as well as images. Would you please like to suggest anything further ? Thank you so much for your precious time and guidance.